Unable to use external SSD for Bitcoin datadir in Ubuntu
I'm learning about how to run a Bitcoin full node. I have started tinkering with it on Windows, and have put the data directory in an external SSD drive I got specifically for storing the entire blockchain data.
I am now looking into moving my setup into a dedicated Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu. I managed to install Bitcoin Core via Snap, however, I'm struggling to point to the Bitcoin data dir in the external SSD.
Ubuntu recognizes it under /media/myUser/Elements and I can see the content via the GUI, but Bitcoin Core fails to start when I point to it in the bitcoin.conf file. I was expecting to see it under /mnt, but not sure why it's not showing up there.
Do I need to partition the external SSD for the Linux filesystem or something of the sort?
Would greatly appreciate any help!

I believe snaps have some security mechanism that prevents them from seeing external disk filesystems. I don't know the solution, so this isn't a full answer, but perhaps it's enough to help figure out what to look for.

This was actually it :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! This worked https://askubuntu.com/a/1345221

As @Pieter Wuille suggested, it had to do with the fact that snap doesn't allow packages to communicate with mounted devices by default.
This helped resolve my issue.
sudo snap connect packagename:removable-media

